# get permalink of page children in loop

Tags: permalinks, child-pages

I have some landing pages that show the page title, feature image and excerpt of their children. The image is linked to the child page, but I need the page title linked to the same place - and I can't figure out how. Here is my existing code - it works perfectly, except the title is not linked. Any recommendations?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php if ( is_page( 'foo' ) ) {
    $pageChildren = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'hierarchical' => '0' ) );
    if ( $pageChildren ) {
    foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
    echo '
    <div class="foo-landing">
  <h2>' . $pageChild->post_title . get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID).'</h2>
  ';
  if ($pageChild->post_excerpt){
  echo '
  <p>'.$pageChild->post_excerpt.'</p>
</div>
';
    }
    }
    }
}
elseif  ( is_page( 'bar' ) ) {
    $pageChildren = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'hierarchical' => '0' ) );
    if ( $pageChildren ) {
    foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
    echo '
    <div class="bar-landing">
  <h2>' . $pageChild->post_title .'</h2>
  ' . get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID);
  if ($pageChild->post_excerpt){
  echo '
  <p>'.$pageChild->post_excerpt.'</p>
  ';
  } echo '</div>
';
    }
    }
}
?>
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using get_page_uri should do the trick:

```
<h2><a href="' . get_page_uri($pageChild) .'">' . $pageChild->post_title . get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID).'</a></h2>
```